# Trying to swap out partials in SPA but layout keeps reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, single-page-application

I am trying to make an SPA and, as far as I understand, the layout should load once and provide a general template for my website and then partials will be loaded in to change the view. I see in my server console and dev tools that the layout and scripts keep getting reloaded when the route changes. How can I stop this so those scripts only get loaded once?

Node Routes:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
```

Node routes.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  console.log('loading layout')
  return res.render('layout');
};

exports.partials = function (req, res) {
  var name = req.params.name;
  console.log('name ', name, ' and loading partial')
  return res.render('partials/' + name);
};
```

Angular Routes:

```
$routeProvider
     .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/index.jade'})
     .when('/someRoute', {templateUrl: 'partials/someRoute.jade', controller: 'myCtrl'})
     .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

layout.jade

```
html
  head
    // bunch of scripts
  body(ng-app='myApp')
    div(ng-view)
      block content
```

folder structure for views is
-views
  -partials
  -layout.jade

If I start type /someRoute into the navigation bar, I see a /someRoute and 404 show up in my server console and 304 for all the scripts included in my layout.jade, but not in my chrome inspector and I never hit enter. If I hit enter, I get the correct response as well as the 404 that must have been queued up and 200 status for all my scripts.

Comment: Need to set `html5Mode` in angular if you aren't using default hash based url's

Comment: I have this right above my routing: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

Comment: ok, i figured it out 10 min after posting. classic. It's a browser thing that if you make the request from the nav bar it will request all new resources with Cache-Control: max-age=0. The scripts being reloaded all have that header even if cache is enabled. Putting a link from within my home page to another view results in only the partial being loaded. Navigating to that route from the URL bar causes everything to be loaded. Makes sense If you're going directly. I went to my home page then changed the route in the nav bar, so I thought those resources are already loaded.